# Sort array of object based on another array

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have an array:

```
const chunks = [
    {id: 0, names: ['app']}, 
    {id: 1, names: ['contact']}, 
    {id: 2, names: ['bootstrap']}
];
```

And I want it to be sorted based on the `names` property, so the order is like in this array:

```
const original = ['bootstrap', 'app', 'contact'];
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind the sort?

Comment: Why is `names` an array, and what should happen when it contains more or less than exactly one item?

Comment: How to handle `{id:999,names:['app', 'bootstrap']}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the delta of the indices of names in original.

```js
const chunks = [{ id: 0, names: ['app'] }, { id: 1, names: ['contact'] }, { id: 2, names: ['bootstrap'] }],
    original = ['bootstrap', 'app', 'contact'];

chunks.sort((a, b) => original.indexOf(a.names[0]) - original.indexOf(b.names[0]));

console.log(chunks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me how this works? What is the "delat of indices"?

Comment: @Michael, it should read *delta*, that is the difference between two values of a same group.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
const chunks = [{id: 0, names: ['app']}, {id: 1, names: ['contact']}, {id: 2, names: ['bootstrap']}];
const original = ['bootstrap', 'app', 'contact'];
let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++) {
        if(chunks[j].names.indexOf(original[i]) !== -1) {
            result.push(chunks[j]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is what I came up with at the beginning, but @NinaScholz way is so much cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: convert chunks into an object so you get the correct one with just the key, then map over the (already sorted) array to plug in the object in place.

```
cMap = chunks.reduce((p,c) => Object.assign( p, {[c.names[0]]: c} ), {});
const sorted = original.map(k => cMap[k]);
```

Comment: Nice approach, but you'll want to mention that this only works when there's exactly one chunk per name.

Comment: True, I didn't take that into consideration. Thankfully there are more discerning eyes on SO than myself :).